# Derivate of determinant for square forms

Tags: matrices, derivatives, linear-transformations, determinant, symmetric-matrices

I'm interesting in derivate of matrix. I have proven that the derivative of a non-symmetric matrix is $d/dA|A| = |A|(A^{-1})^T$, when $A^{-1}$ exists and if the matrix is symmetric $d/dS|S| = |S|(2S^{-1}-diag(S^{-1})$. Now, I need to prove that the $d/dA |A^TSA| = 2|A^TSA|SA(A^TSA)^{-1}$ where $S$ is simetric matrix, any suggestion to prove this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the matrix
$$\eqalign{
 X &= A^TSA \\
}$$
You already know the gradient of $\det(X)$, so let's use that to calculate the differential, then perform a change of variables from $X\to A$.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \det(X) \\
d\phi
 &= \phi X^{-T}:dX \\
 &= \phi X^{-T}:\big(A^TS\,dA+dA^TSA\big) \\
 &= \phi SAX^{-T}:dA \,+\, \phi SAX^{-1}:dA \\
 &= \phi SA\big(X^{-T}+X^{-1}\big):dA \\
 &= 2\phi SAX^{-1}:dA \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A}
 &= 2\phi SAX^{-1} \\
}$$
where a colon represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$\;A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$.

The properties of the trace allow the terms in a such a product to be rearranged in various ways.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for having responded, you have helped me a lot with your argument.